# Java Chess scorekeeper

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I'm grateful if anyone could help with the below. I am trying to make a scorekeeper for my chessboard. At the moment, the score will go back to zero everytime. How would I be able to save the previous score and add it every move? Thanks!

```
public static int scoreKeeper(Chessmen[][] chessboard, int X, int Y, int X1, int Y1, int currentNumber, int totalNumber){

    AbstractPiece knight = new Knight();
    AbstractPiece bishop = new Bishop();
    AbstractPiece pawn = new Pawn();
    AbstractPiece king = new King();
    AbstractPiece queen = new Queen();
    AbstractPiece rook = new Rook();

    if ((chessboard[Y][X] == Chessmen.WHITE_KNIGHT) || 
            (chessboard[Y][X] == Chessmen.BLACK_KNIGHT)){
        currentNumber = currentNumber+totalNumber+knight.relativeValue();
        return currentNumber;
    }else return totalNumber;
}
```

Comment: What variable represents the `previous score`?

Comment: " the score will go back to zero everytime." What do you mean "everytime"?  Every time you run the program or every time you call `scoreKeeper` in the same running program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you have is that you are passing the value of currentNumber as a parameter 
that means it will not change outside this method 
this Example will illustrate my point

```
public class Test{

   public static void main (String[] args){
       int a = 0 ;
       changeValue(a);
       System.out.print(a);
   }
   public static  void changeValue(int a){
       a=20;
   }
}
```

the output will be always 0 .

you can solve it by writing the methods  **getValueOfCurrentNumber()** and **getValueOfTotalNumbe()**

to get the values **[currentNumber and totalNumbe]**  instead of taking them as parameters .

Comment: Thanks iShaalan, could you give me any tips I can make a getValue method? Do I need a class data member as well? Really appreciate it.

Comment: As well, you should probably be more descriptive with those variable names. Get total number of...?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to store your score as a class data member:

```
class Game {
    static int score;

    public static int updateScore(... some inputs...) {
        if(some condition is true) {
            score = score + whatever you want to add;
        }
    }
}
```

The class retains the value of "score" between method calls.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have a bad abstraction.  I think you want a `Chessboard` to hide the 2D array of `Chessmen`.  Let it keep the current score as a data member.  Provide methods to select and move pieces appropriately.

I can see its constructor instantiating a Chessboard.  It would set each of the pieces at their appropriate starting positions.  Then each Player would take turns moving.

Not a trivial problem.